# Why is the slope of stacked concentric circles 2*pi*r? (About a calculus video by 3Blue1Brown.)

Tags: calculus, geometry, circles, area

[View the video here.](https://youtu.be/WUvTyaaNkzM?t=4m18s)

In the video, Grant, its creator, breaks down the area formula of a circle.

---

*Explaining the video as best I can:*

He divides the circle into numerous smaller, concentric circles, each with a thickness *dr* and length 2 x pi x *R*. (He uses the *r* notation again, but I'll go with R so as not to confuse the two.)

He then unravels the circles into lines and approximates them with rectangles, the area of which we can easily compute with *dr* x (2 x pi x *R*). After that, Grant places each line on an x-y graph, where the x axis represents the thickness (*dr*) and the y the length (2 x pi x *R*).

He runs a line from origin over the triangle-ish shape formed by these figures (hard to explain, please see the video) and says its slope is 2 x pi x *r*. **Here, I get stuck.**

---

According to my own calculations — and I may be wrong here — the formula for R is *r* / (*N* - *n*), where *N* is the total number of concentric circles and *n* is the distance of a specific circle from the center.

So, to find the slope, I plugged two pairs of values calculated with that formula and simply *dr* into the standard slope formula — (y_1 - y_2) / (x_1 - x_2) — and got **(pi x r) / 3 x *dr*.** If I plug in the value of *dr* in this example, which is 3/4 (I have 4 concentric rings), I get (4 x pi x *r*)/9, which still isn't right.

[Here's how.](https://photos.app.goo.gl/X364abL7tmXALBYG7)

---

I know I went wrong *somewhere*. But I don't know whether there's a computational error I made along the way that I cannot find or if I'm misunderstanding something in the video.

Comment: Grant drew the graph of $y=2\pi r$ and said the slope was $2\pi$. That is at 5:26 to 5:29 in his video.  The x-axis is R (or r. I'm not sure how you see them as different.) Your mistake might be in assuming the x-axis is $dr$, when it is really $r$

Comment: Yes, that must be it! I both kept looking at the x axis in term of *dr* and assumed the slope was 2 x pi x r, because it was written so above it. What a stupid problem. Will you post that as an answer? I'll mark it as correct. Tomorrow. (Going to sleep, now. Timezones.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant drew the graph of y=2πr and said the slope was 2π. That is at 5:26 to 5:29 in his video. The x-axis is R (or r. I'm not sure how you see them as different.) Your mistake might be in assuming the x-axis is $dr$, when it is really $r$